# Back button causes bottom navigation to disappear

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hi im new in react native. I have added a back button to a SchoolSelector screen but for some reason, the bottom tab disappear when i navigate to back. I am using a stack and have provided that below as well

I am not sure if this is enough information to truly answer my question. Please do not hesitate to ask me to provide more!

Here's my bottom tab:

```
const AuthStack = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={({route}) => ({
            tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.dodgerBlue,
            tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: Colors.melrose,
            headerShown: false
        })}>
            <Tab.Screen options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    return <Ionicons name="home-sharp" size={size} color={color} />;
                }
            }} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    return <Ionicons name="person-sharp" size={size} color={color} />;
                }
            }} name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    return <Ionicons name="receipt-sharp" size={size} color={color} />;
                }
            }} name="Ledger" component={LedgerScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                    return <Ionicons name="settings-sharp" size={size} color={color} />;
                }
            }} name="Settings" component={SettingScreen} />
            
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Here's my stack navigator

```
<NavigationContainer independent={true}>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Login" component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Register" component={RegisterScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="ChangeEmail" component={ChangeEmailScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePasswordScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="SchoolSelector" component={SchoolSelectorScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Settings" component={SettingScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="UpdateNumber" component={UpdateNumberScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPasswordScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={AuthStack}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Ledger" component={LedgerScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="SubjectProfile" component={SubjectProfileScreen}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Here's my header screen which uses appbar to display title on every screen with back button.

```
export const HeaderComponent = (props: HeaderComponentParams) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <Appbar style={mainStyles.AppBarStyle}>
            <Button onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Settings') }} uppercase={false} style={styles.backText}>Back</Button>
            <Appbar.Content style={{ alignItems: 'center', right: 30 }} title={props.title} />
        </Appbar>
    );
}
```

Comment: So you want to disable the default back button that comes from the stack and instead use your own back button, that always and every time navigates to `Settings`? Or did you miss that the StackNavigator comes with a nice back button build-in?

Comment: Yes bro i tried build-in goBack() and pop() method, but it gives me ```The action 'POP' with payload {"count":1} was not handled by any navigator.```. That's why i resorted to this code to go back to settings page ```navigation.navigate('Settings')```

Comment: So you would be happy if the default back button worked? This guide should give you the basics: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution

Comment: Yes bro anything. As long that the buttom tab doesn't disappear when i press the back button i created.

Comment: Thanks man for pointing me out to the right direction. This help me solve the problem.